# Deploy Django 2.0 on Apache 2.2 at ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

My enviroment:

ubuntu 12.04 / python3.6.4 / django 2.0 / apache 2.2.22

I want to deploy newsite on apache

I followed [django official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

I want to deploy at

www.domainname.com/newsite/

my httpd.conf

```
<Directory /home/usr/project_name/project_name>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess site python-path=/home/usr/site
WSGIProcessGroup site
WSGIScriptAlias /newsite/  /home/usr/project_mame/project_name/wsgi.py
```

if I add my virtual environment in python-home, I can't pass configtest

I browse 127.0.0.1 it shows apache 'It works' page

but 127.0.0.1/newsite i just got 403 forbidden

log: client denied by server configuration: xxxxxx/xxxxxx/wsgi.py

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 12.04 has reached end of life and does not receive security updates.

Comment: my company still use 12.04 ..... :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
<VirtualHost *:9002>

        ServerName complete_hostname #result of hostname -f

        WSGIDaemonProcess Django_project_name python-path=/var/www/html/Django_project_name
        WSGIProcessGroup Django_project_name 
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/Django_project_name/Django_project_name /wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/html/Django_project_name/Django_project_name >
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted               
        </Files>
        </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are using a version of Apache older than 2.4, replace `Require all granted` with `Allow from all` and also add the line `Order deny,allow` above it.

Comment: if for development  'eg.com' can be replaced 127.0.01?

Comment: no. check `hostname -f ` and write instead of eg.com

Comment: I have virtual enviroment, does it need set python-homne?

Comment: when i set python-home=/home/shinsoft/newsite/virtual_env 
Apache says ' Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition'

Comment: @LJC thanks for accepting my answer. It seems it solved your problem :)